# How can make a history for an Android app?

Tags: java, android

How can I make a history for operations ?

I need to save the results in an Array and then  a redender  with ListActivity in Android.

This is the code  :

```
public void calculator(){
    EditText screen = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.screen);

    if (screen.getText().toString().equals(".")){
        screen.setText("0");
    }
    if (screen.getText().toString().length() > 0){
        this.Operand2 = Float.parseFloat(screen.getText().toString());
    }
    if (this.Operator.equals("+")) {
        this.Answer = this.Operand1 + this.Operand2;
    } else if (this.Operator.equals("-")){
        this.Answer = this.Operand1 - this.Operand2;    
    } else if (this.Operator.equals("*")){
        this.Answer =this.Operand1 * this.Operand2;
    } else if (this.Operator.equals("/")){
        this.Answer = this.Operand1 / this.Operand2;
    }else if (this.Operator.equals("^")){
        this.Answer = (float) Math.pow(this.Operand1, this.Operand2);
    }else if (this.Operator.equals("%")){
        this.Answer = Operand1 % this.Operand2;
    }else{
        this.Answer = Float.parseFloat(screen.getText().toString());
    }

    screen.setText(this.Answer + "");
```

And this is the array  Adapter :

```
la1 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, ARRAY_NAME);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In class with method calculator() add field:

```
private List<String> history = new LinkedList<String>();
```

Then, add Answer to this List:

```
screen.setText(this.Answer + "");
list.add(this.Answer);
```

Now list contains history for operations (Answers).

Answer (score 0):

don't make calculator like this. parse whole expression instead of 'char by char'. (LALR could do this perfectly)

for exactly what to use, `bison`, this tool will gen code for you.